# Why recent project and solution pinned always is false?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing a extension package for VS 2019, So far i find out how to get "Recent projects and solutions" items, These items have a PropertyInfo called "Pinned" which means that project or solution is pinned, Except it's always false.

Here is the code which i get project list and show it to user :

```
 IVsDataSourceFactory objFactory = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsDataSourceFactory)) as IVsDataSourceFactory;
            objFactory.GetDataSource(new Guid("9099ad98-3136-4aca-a9ac-7eeeaee51dca"), 1, out IVsUIDataSource dataSource);
            Type typProjectMruList = Type.GetType("Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ProjectMruList, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal", true);
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo itemsProperty = typProjectMruList.GetProperty("Items");
            Type typFileSystemMruItem = Type.GetType("Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.FileSystemMruItem, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal", true);
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pathProperty = typFileSystemMruItem.GetProperty("Path");
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pinnedProperty = typFileSystemMruItem.GetProperty("Pinned");
            IList lstItems = (IList)itemsProperty.GetValue(dataSource, null);
            string strMsg = "";
            for (var i = lstItems.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                string strPath = (string)pathProperty.GetValue(lstItems[i], null);
                bool blnPinned = (bool)pinnedProperty.GetValue(lstItems[i], null);
                strMsg = strMsg + "Path : " + strPath + Environment.NewLine + "Pinned : " + blnPinned.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            // Show a message box to prove we were here
            VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
                package,
                strMsg,
                "",
                OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
                OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
                OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
```

Anyone tried to do something like this before? Or this is a bug and i should report it to microsoft?

If you want to test this code just create a new command and put this code in "Execute" void.

Comment: I test your code in my side and face the same issue. I have reported it to the staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone tried to do something like this before? Or this is a bug and i
>   should report it to microsoft?

Based on your description, when I try your code and when I debug this project, create a new project in solution explorer, I faced the same issue as you said: the value of `blnPinned` is always false though the project is pinned.

[image]

So l have reported this issue on our DC Forum for you. See [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/960772/when-i-create-a-project-created-by-my-vsix-project.html) which I hope anyone who is interested in this issue will vote for you.

You can vote on this issue and add any comment if I forgot some detailed info to attract more attention. With this further step, I hope the staff will give a satisfactory feedback.

Comment: Thank you for your time to report this problem, After i findout you have same problem atleast i know i'm not only one who get Pinned false, I hope they answer that soon.